# How to set Name/Email using MassPayments API

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the PHP version of the Paypal Mass Payments API (https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php) and I'm having difficulty finding out where or how to fill in the "Name/Email" field for payments.

Looking at the screenshot below, I have sent a bunch of payments but the "Name/Email" field is just a generic "Mass Payment" (I'm assuming that PayPal's servers filled that in).  Obviously, I've set the recipient's email address, but that doesn't show on the transaction log whatsoever.

Is there anyway to fill in that Name/Email column?

[image: masspayments_transactions]

This is my code:

```
    $massPayRequest = new MassPayRequestType();
    $massPayRequest->MassPayItem = array();
    $masspayItem = new MassPayRequestItemType();
    $masspayItem->Amount = new BasicAmountType('USD', $cash_bal);
    $masspayItem->ReceiverEmail = $email_paypal;
    $massPayRequest->MassPayItem[] = $masspayItem;
    $massPayReq = new MassPayReq();
    $massPayReq->MassPayRequest = $massPayRequest;
    $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService($config_mp);
    $massPayResponse = $paypalService->MassPay($massPayReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PayPal account overview page is only going to show the "Mass Payment" transaction in the history list.  When you click into the transaction details, though, you get a better break-down of all the payments included in that Mass Payment.  You also have the ability there to download a CSV which includes all of the individual payments along with the name, email for each.

Alternatively, you could setup an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) solution, and then when the Mass Payment occurs PayPal's server will POST that detail to your URL which can receive the data and process it accordingly.

IPN is definitely the recommended method.  It happens in real-time and will allow you to fully automate any tasks you need to manage those payments.

I'd recommend taking a look at [this PHP IPN template](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template).  It'll get you up and running very quickly with IPN, and then you can make adjustments to suit your needs.